# How do I create a category tree, where subcategories can have multiple parents?

Tags: php, mysql

I need create some functions that return an array of categories and subcategories, where subcategories can have more then one parent. I have tried to solve this problem for maybe 6 days but there's nothing on internet.

Here is some code I have created, but it doesn't work.

```
    private function getAllSubs($category, $index, $parent = null)
 {
  $subs = $this->database->table('eshop_product_categoryo')
  ->where('parent', $category->id);

  $haveSub = false;
  foreach($subs as $sub)
  {
    $haveSub = true; 
    break;
  }

  if($haveSub)
  {
   $mainCategory = $this->database->table('eshop_product_categoryo')
   ->where('category', $category->id);

   $isMainCategory = true;
   foreach($mainCategory as $main)
   {
    $isMainCategory = false; 
    break;
   }

   $ppp = 0;

   if(!$isMainCategory)
   {
    $ppp = $parent;
   }

   $this->someArray[] = array
   (
    'name'  => $category->name,
    'parent'  => $ppp,
    'index' => $index,
    'id'    => $category->id
   );

   foreach($subs as $sub)
   {
    $ctgry = $this->database->table('eshop_product_category')
    ->where('id', $sub->category)
    ->fetch();
    $this->getAllSubs($ctgry, ($index+1), $sub->parent);
   }
  }
 }
```

Comment: So can you start with information on your database schema?  It seems like currently you are accessing only a single table, which would be very problematic when trying to describe a many-to-many relationship.  Your problem here likely has nothing to do with your code and everything to do with your data model.

Comment: create table categories(
   id int unsigned primary key auto_increment,
   name varchar(255)
);

create table subs(
    id int unsigned primary key auto_increment,
    category int unsigned,
    father int unsigned // category id
);

Comment: @Zdenek, ^ please add that table definition into your question - you can add it nicely formatted in the question, whereas it is hard to make it readable in the comments. Also, if something "doesn't work", it is better to describe what you expected and what you got, otherwise people will have to try to work out in what way it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok finally solved... ;-) here is almost finally version

```
private function getAllSubs($category, $index)
 {
  $subs = $this->database->table('eshop_product_categoryo')
  ->where('otec', $category->id);

  $hasSub = false;
  foreach($subs as $sub){$hasSub = true; break;}

  if($hasSub)
  {
   $this->someArray[] = array
   (
    'name'  => $category->name,
    'index' => $index
   );
   foreach($subs as $sub)
   {
    $parent = $this->database->table('eshop_product_category')
    ->where('id', $sub->category)
    ->fetch();
    $this->getAllSubs($parent, ($index + 1));
   }
  }
  else
  {
   $this->someArray[] = array
   (
    'name'  => $category->name,
    'index' => $index
   );
  }
 }
```

Comment: I'm sure this solution works for you but in future you might want to know that what you are trying to implement is called a linked list, it's a basic and very useful CS solution to master.